# Riemann integrals and continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $d>0$ be a number. Is there a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is not Riemann integrable on the interval $[a-d, a+d]$ if $f$ is continuous at $x = a$?

Comment: Pick $g$ nonintegrable and squeeze $g$ ($f(x)=g(x)({\rm something})$) near $a$.

Comment: This was asked yesterday, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660982/integrating-real-valued-functions).

Comment: moreover, it was asked by the same person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Take f to be constant near $x=a$, and it will equal dirichlet function, $\chi _{\mathbb{Q}}$, near $a-d,a+d$.

Explicitly: for $|x-a|<\frac{d}{2}$ take $f=1$, and so it will be continuous near $a$, and at all other $x$ values take it to equal $0$ if x is irrational, and $f=1$ if $x$ is rational.